# How to handle keyup events in main game loop?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, game-loop

I'm writing a simple game in JavaScript, which already handles basic keyboard input like so:

```
var input = {};
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    input[e.keyCode] = true;
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    input[e.keyCode] = false;
}

while (!done) {
    handleInput(input);
    update();
    render();
}
```

Now I need the game to handle key combos (like CTRL+X for example). I would like it to accept such combos **on `keyup` only**.

**EDIT:** Modifier keys don't need to go all up at the same time as the "main" key. **/EDIT**

Two possible solutions that come into my mind are:

- exposing an array containing a list of `keyup` events (object with "main" key plus modifiers). The `handleInput` function would be responsible for draining the queue every time it polls it
- keeping track of possible key combos inside `handleInput` (watching for held down modifier keys) and trigger the combo behavior when the "main" key goes up (I actually don't like this that much)

Would you suggest me an elegant way to extend the current functionality?

Comment: Anyways, good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to create `upInput` variable where you will store your keyup keys in. Then, to check if the combo was pressed you have to check if there is only `CTRL + C` (or 17, 67) combo in variable and if all of them were `true`. Then easily print your message and reset `upInput` variable.

```
var input = upInput = {};

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    input[e.keyCode] = true;
    if (JSON.stringify(Object.keys(upInput)) != '["17","67"]')
        upInput = {};
}
document.onkeyup = function(e) {
    var k = e.keyCode;
    input[k] = false;
    if ([17, 67].indexOf(k) > -1)
        upInput[k] = true;
    if (JSON.stringify(Object.keys(upInput)) == '["17","67"]'
            && upInput[17] && upInput[67]) // CTRL + C
        alert('YES!'),
        upInput = {};
}
```

## [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oz36ww89/3/)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Mmm... can I say I don't like the `JSON.stringify(Object.keys(upInput)) == '["17","67"]'` bit?  Also, the event handlers should just update the input state, which should be handled by the `handleInput` function in the main loop (the code in my question is wrong, I'm going to fix it)

Comment: @MarcoBolis `JSON.stringify()` was the fastest option, else I had to make a custom `.contains()` function for Object prototype. As I can understand, you don't like to have code inside your event listeners? Then it isn't possible. Also, you haven't declare `done` variable so your while statement is pointless in current code.

Comment: no problem about the code inside the listeners, we just take the _handling_ part out and slam it into `handleInput`.  About the bit I didn't like, it's not about `JSON.stringify()`, it's just that I don't trust `Object.keys()` to return keys in the right order!

Comment: @MarcoBolis so what's wrong with the code? By the way, to have keys in right order just simply sort them with `.sort()` function :)

Comment: since you are already checking `upInput[17] && upInput[67]`, why not just check `Object.keys(upInput).length === 2`? Faster, cleaner, happier ;-)  You could also use an array instead of a plain object, I was thinking...

Comment: @MarcoBolis sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try this ;)
It will appear a message when you press CTRL + X and you release one (or both) of them

```
var map = {17: false, 88: false};
var fire_event = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
        if (map[17] && map[88]) {
            fire_event = true;
        }
    }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }
    if (fire_event) {
        fire_event = false;
        alert('YOU PRESSED CTRL + X');
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: First time it works, but after I press ctrl+x combo again it fails.

Comment: Try it now, I made a change... I didn't see that was specified "on keyup only."

Comment: No. What if I press `CTRL + X + A` and let `A`? Or `CTRL + X` and then `CTRL + C`?

Answer (score 0):

I would do in one of those ways:

- Checking for the combinations in the handleInput part (kind of your
  second apporach)
- Keeping a list of the very last X keyboard events (where X is max
  length of combo sequence) and checking whether this list matches to
  any of the predefined combo triggers

Answer (score 0):

Try if it works:

```
var KEY_QUEUE = [];
var KEYs = [17, 88];

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (KEY_QUEUE.indexOf(e.keyCode) === -1) {
        KEY_QUEUE.push(e.keyCode);
    }
};

document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    var index = KEY_QUEUE.indexOf(e.keyCode);
    if ( isSubArray(KEYs, KEY_QUEUE) 
         && KEYs.indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1 ) {
        console.log("You press CTRL + X");
    }
    KEY_QUEUE.splice(index, 1);
};

function isSubArray(ary, targetAry) {
  return new RegExp(ary.toString()).test(targetAry.toString());
}
```

I've checked some cases like `Ctrl x`, `x Ctrl`, `Ctrl x a`, `Ctrl a x`, and it works as I expected. But I am not sure if it is the same with you idea.

Comment: Doesn't this solution require the user to release the keys in the exact order?

Comment: @Marco Bolis, it requires. `Ctrl x` will trigger the event, `x Ctrl` will not. And `Ctrl a x` will not work if you up unpress x or Ctrl first, but it works if you uppress `a` first to leave `Ctrl` and `x` together.